# Getting "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, tkinter, import

Been getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error and can't figure out why that is, if someone could help help me that would be very much appreciated.

```
from tkinter import * from tkinter import filedialog import os from
tkinter import messagebox

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Pythonscript\\Notepad')



def savenote():
    usernotes = note_text.get("1.0", END)
    result = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialfile = 'Untitled.txt',title = 'Save your note', mode='w', defaultextension = '.txt')
    if result:
        result.write(usernotes)
        result.close()

def open_note():
   openf = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = 
     ('C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Pythonscript\\Notepad'), title 
     = ' Select Your Note', filetypes =(("Text File", "*.txt"),("All 
     Files","*.*")))
   note_text.delete('1.0', END)
   file_path = os.path.join(openf)
   file_obj = open(file_path)
   file_contents = file_obj.read()
   note_text.insert(END, file_contents)
   b = note_text.get('1.0', END)
   openf.write()
   openf.close()

screen = Tk() screen.title('Note App') screen.resizable
screen.geometry('800x800')

def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        screen.destroy()

screen.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)


note_s = StringVar() Label1 = Label(screen, text = 'Write a note: ',
bg = '#a84646', fg = 'white', font=('Courier New' ,16, 'bold'),
borderwidth = 2, relief='groove', width=200, height = 2).pack()
note_text = Text(screen, height = 50, width = 270, bg = 'white',
borderwidth=2, relief= 'groove', font=(None,12), state = 'normal')note_text.pack()

menu = Menu(screen) screen.config(menu = menu)

filemenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0) menu.add_cascade(label = 'File',menu = filemenu) filemenu.add_command(label= 'Open File', command = open_note) filemenu.add_separator() filemenu.add_command(label= 'Save File', command = savenote)


screen.mainloop()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Pythonscript/Notepad/tkinter Vers2.py", line 21, in open_note
    file_obj = open(file_path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: In which line are you getting this error? Please notice that if you are trying to load a file, you need to write its suffix ,`.txt` for example, as well.

Comment: that is the entire error:   

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\donovan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/donovan/Documents/Pythonscript/Notepad/tkinter Vers2.py", line 21, in open_note
    file_obj = open(file_path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: The reason is literally the error: the file doesn’t exist. Have you examined the value in `file_path` to see if it is what you are assuming it is?

Comment: The error only occurs whenever I click open file and then don't actually choose a file and just click on the 'x', so i guess that's why it says no file found but it's still annoying getting the error message.

Comment: Yes, if you dismiss the dialog without choosing a file, it will return an empty string. That’s how it is designed and documented to work.

Comment: @lnasal Add the line `if not openf: return` before `note_text.delete('1.0', END)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you said this only happens if you dismiss the dialog without selecting a file. In that case, the dialog function is designed to return an empty string.

You simply need to account for this and return from your function without loading if `openf` is empty, since there is nothing to load.